# how to enable 1MB dma-kmalloc

Tags: kernel, ram

I'm running a ubuntu 15.10 VM and testing code that will allocate 1MB dma buffers.  However, from the /proc/slabinfo, the max that can be allocated is 8K

```
dma-kmalloc-8192       0      0   8192    4    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-4096       0      0   4096    8    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-2048       0      0   2048   16    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-1024       0      0   1024   16    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-512       16     16    512   16    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      1      1      0
```

Does anyone know how to enable **dma-kmalloc-1048576**?

Thanks